# Getting return data from a transaction hash using Nethereum

Tags: nethereum

I'm using Nethereum to call a non-view/non-constant function of a smart contract that modifies the state of the smart contract and returns a boolean value.

The result of submitting this transaction is a transaction hash.

Is there a way in Nethereum to then use the returned transaction hash to get the boolean value returned by the smart contract method? I have found ways to do this for view functions, but can't find anything on non-view functions.